# Grafana count the variable items

Tags: grafana

Is it possible to get a count of the items within a variable defined in Grafana?

For example, if I have defined a variable called 'name' which is a multi-valued variable with the ALL option enabled. How can I create a gauge / stat or any suitable chart that counts the number of distinct values of 'name' that this variable inherits from other choices?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I managed this for now with the following panel on Grafana -

```
   with m as (
      select distinct name from db.schema.table
      where name in (${<variableName>:singlequote}) and $__timeFilter(timestamp) 
    )
    select count(*) from m
```

Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the glob filter option (https://play.grafana.org/d/cJtIfcWiz/template-variable-formatting-options?orgId=1) and get the difference between the resulting string with and without the commas, plus 1, like this:

```
select len('${your_variable_here:glob}')-len(replace('${your_variable_here>:glob}',',',''))+1
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used this on Google BigQuery as the datasource:

`SELECT ARRAY_LENGTH(${var_name:json})`

`${var_name:json}` converts the var_name into `ARRAY<string>` type.
You can view all variable interpolations here:
[Grafana Variable Interpolations](https://play.grafana.org/d/HYaGDGIMk/templating-global-variables-and-interpolation?orgId=1)